# Count rows in a textfile

Tags: c#, winforms

I´m coding in C# and using Windows Forms.
I have a textfile and want to count all rows that are in it.

Peter;25

John;31

Jane;22

Thats three lines and i want to count them for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way would be to use something like:

```
var count = File.ReadLines("file.txt").Count();
```

That will only work in .NET 4, but will read a single line at a time. If you're happy enough to load the whole file into memory in one go, you can use:

```
var count = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Length;
```

Note that if the file is large (or it's on a network drive etc), this could take a long time, in which case you'd want to do it off the UI thread.

Comment: Where is EnumerateAllLines defined?

Comment: I used var count = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Length; and it worked great thanks alot!

Comment: @Simon: My mistake, it's File.ReadLines. I've fixed the answer. Still only as of .NET 4 though.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is not too big, you can do this:

```
File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Length;
```

(this will allocate the whole file, so make sure performance is not an issue)

Comment: Thnaks for the answear and it worked but i used the answear above.

Answer (score 1):

```
        string fileName = @"X:\Testfolder\countthis.txt";
        int lineCount = 0;

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);
        Assert.Fail();

        while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
            lineCount++;
        return lineCount;
```

Comment: You should use C# using statement or make sure you call Dispose on the FileStream

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't think about that :-) Sorry